# the correct way to work with pytest rest api

Tags: python, api, testing, automation, pytest

consider im write test api
its enought to just check if equal to the code (200,201,etc)
and print the content like this example:

```
import requests
import pytest


def test_one():
    res = requests.get("someurl")
    assert res.status_code == 200
    print(res.json())

def test_one():
    data = {"name":"string"}
    res = requests.put("someurl",json=data)
    assert res.status_code == 200
    print(res.json())
```

or im need also check if the contents are same like the excepted ?
like this example:

```
def test_one():
    data = {"name":"string"}
    res = requests.put("someurl",json=data)
    assert res.status_code == 200
    assert data == res.json()
```

Comment: check if the contents are same

Comment: You have an example how to do it correctly?

Comment: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-tests/

Comment: The right tests can change depending on expectations you have. What do you expect "someurl" to do exactly? Is it supposed to repeat back the JSON argument? (The last code you wrote implies that.) Or do you expect the request to succeed and that's all? Or do you expect to get some non-empty response?

Comment: Generally you shouldn’t print in a test. If you need the results to conform to specific formats or values you should test these with assertions

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things to validate,  the most common being the response `json`

```
import json
response_json = json.loads(response.text)
```

from here you can validate the values in `dict` format.

sometimes you need to validate the response `json schema` also